# Apache2 Virtual host on mint

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup apache virtual host on Mint linux. It kinda works, but some images are not available. For example http://test.local/icons/world.png returns 404 even if image exist. When I check log it says it's looking for image at **/usr/share/apache2/icons/world.png** even if I setup my DocumentRoot to /var/www/test.local/public_html

This is how I did this. copy /etc/apache2/sites-available/default to test.local and edit like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.local   

    DocumentRoot /var/www/test.local/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/test.local/public_html/>

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I edit /etc/hosts and include **127.0.0.1 test.local** in it. Run **a2ensite test.local** and restart apache.

What I try to do is map folder in my **/var/www/test.local/public_html** to **http://test.local** is there anything I'm missing, or easier way to do this.

Also to mention there is no .htaccess file in root directory of project, or in icons directory.

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVED :)

This is 2nd time I'm answering my own questions here on SO. I actually was researching 2 days and found answer few hours after posting here.

Answer was that this is default Apache alias

```
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons/"
```

Even if I couldn't find it in **apache2.conf** or in **conf.d** directory, it looks like it's there in **/etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf** under my Mint distribution (I guess all Debian distro will have similar path). All I needed to do is to comment out this alias and it works.